# Changing Tag Type When Extending Component in Styled-Components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a Styled-Component called `Headline` that I wish to extend with another component called `SubHeadline`.  Now, `Headline` looks like this:

```
const Headline = styled.h2`
// Css styles go here
`
```

What I would like to do is to both extend the styles of Headline AND change the tag type to something else (say h3).  Something like this:

```
const SubHeadline = styled(Headline).h3`
// Css styles go here
`
```

Now the above does NOT work, but it illustrates what I would like to do.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way I know how to manage this is described in [this Github Issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/773#issuecomment-299667585). 
Put all your functionality out in variables and added it to your different child components:

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'

const HeadlineStyles = css`
  // Css for Headline here
`

const Headline = styled.h2`
  ${HeadlineStyles}
`

const SubHeadline = styled.h3`
  ${HeadlineStyles}
`
```

Comment: Thanks -- that will do it.

Comment: That's the best solution i've found to make a button component that can be a simple 'a' tag or a Link from react-router-dom

Comment: @TiagoDamascena Another good way is to change the type in your jsx like this: `<YourButton as="a">Submit</YourButton>`. But you have to do this for each component when you're using it. But helpful if you have it as a `Link`-styled component but want an external link.